C - STM32 - Calling function inside while statement causing a crash
I am programming an STM32 in C, and have written a custom read function to make my life easier, utilising the CMSIS files.
uint32_t ReadBits(volatile uint32_t *Reg, uint32_t Mask)
{
    uint32_t tmp = *Reg & Mask; // temporary reg holding isolated values
    uint32_t position = __builtin_ctz(Mask); // Find the trailing amount of 0's
    return tmp >> position;
}

However, when I'm calling this function inside an interrupt, it triggers the hardfault_handler. I am implementing it like this:
void EXTI4_15_IRQHandler(void)
{
    while(ReadBits(&GPIOC->IDR, GPIO_IDR_ID6) == 0)
    {
        GPIOB->ODR = GPIO_ODR_OD2; // Stall interrupt and keep LED on
    }
    GPIOB->ODR = 0; // Turn LED off
    EXTI->FPR1 &= EXTI_FPR1_FPIF6; // Clear flag
}

Two things to note:

When I am debugging and place a breakpoint right at the start, it doesn't have any issues. It almost feels like I am giving the CPU time to breathe. The problem arises when I don't place any breakpoints in the ISR.
When I replace the inside of the while statement with ((GPIOC->IDR >> GPIO_IDR_ID6_Pos) & 0b1) == 0, there's no dramas at all. Confirming that it is the function call.

What is the issue here and how can I keep the ease of use of a custom function will maintaining stability? Please ignore the blocking nature of a while statement inside the ISR, I know it's not good practice, this is just a test project.

Could you define that function as static inline?

The problem, I think, is that you want to use the pointer reference as the first parameteruint32_t ReadBits(volatile uint32_t *Reg, uint32_t Mask). I think the better way is simple decl uint32_t ReadBits(volatile uint32_t Reg, uint32_t Mask) and usage ReadBits(GPIOC->IDR, GPIO_IDR_ID6

Do you have the option to use instruction trace? And see where from you ended up in the hardfault handler, more specifically. Also you should put a breakpoint in the hardfault handler and check the stack pointer, since stack overflow is always one of the usual culprits for bugs like this. I'd also step into __builtin_ctz and see exactly how they implemented it - to rule out that it doesn't do incredibly stupid things like recursion.

Hard fault means you have triggered one of the other faults (eg: bus fault) but it is disabled.  Enable the various faults and read the corresponding registers (eg: bus fault address register BFAR) to see what is actually wrong.

@Lundin I forgot to mention that the while(1){} loop has some ReadBits() called in it too. I imagine if the main is mid ReadBits() and the ISR is called, the ISR is calling itself to a place where the main is halted, and rewriting the memory of the main, causing issues. Can both access the same function at once?

@TomV I will enable proper fault handling to see what I can find. I actually am not sure how to quickly find the problem when I hit a hard fault.

@Gerhardh I’ll give it a go. What should that change in terms of operation or compilation?

@ezra_vdj If the built-in isn't re-entrant but uses static storage variables internally, then sure, that can would cause mayhem. You'd have to peek at the implementation to see what it is doing.

@Lundin on what crazy planet would count-trailing-zeros need static storage? At worst on CM0 it might need a couple of registers, but in this case I hope it would be evaluated at compile time. :-D

@TomV Sounds unlikely indeed, but nothing surprises me any longer. I wouldn't rule anything out before checking the implementation. For example on some MCU (not ARM) the lib might decide to allocate a chunk of static memory in zero page for faster arithmetic compared to the stack.

@ezra_vdj making the function static inline could cause the compiler to remove the function call and add the code directly in the caller function. If there is any issue with your stack that might not happen without the call. Inlining the function might also enable more optimization if the argument for clz is known at compile time.

@Gerhardh defining them as static inline functions seems to have removed the issue for me!

You should still try to find the root cause, as Lundin already mentioned.

I'm sure the problem has something to do with the overhead of calling and running a function, but not specifically sure.
However, by reimplementing the ReadBits function as a #define macro the problem is fixed, and the code is just as easy to use. It looks like this:
#define ReadBits(REG, MASK) (((REG) & (MASK)) >> __builtin_ctz(MASK))


Can you compare assembler code for both working and non-working versions?

If you haven't found the root cause then you haven't solved the problem. Inlining the code as a macro cures a symptom of the bug, not the root cause of the bug. You can't just say "it is fixed now" without knowing why and then merrily be on your way.
